# what is the equivalent of CustomMasterUrl.SetInherit in CSOM

Tags: 2013, 2010, csom

in C#

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
PublishingWeb publishingWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
publishingWeb.CustomMasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/mycustom.master";
publishingWeb.CustomMasterUrl.SetInherit(true, true);
publishingWeb.Update();
```

this code will change the master page and "Reset all subsites to inherit masterpage"

Is there a CSOM equivalent for **CustomMasterUrl.SetInherit(true,true)**?